# Ionic : ngCordova not responding : Cannot read property 'file' of undefined

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I'm trying to load cordova-plugin-file (from ngCordova). All of [this doc](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/) has been done. Here is my code :

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaFile) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      console.log(window.cordova.file);
  }
}
```

(the same with or without "window.")
and here is the result :

> Cannot read property 'file' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found the answer : ngCordova cannot run properly in the browser. I used Ripple emulator (Chrome extension) to run my app and see the logs. And actually the logs told me that my code was right.

Comment: No, ngCordova works totally fine; it is just that Cordova plugins do not work on a browser, because they comprise of native code, meant for mobile OS environment only.